# Pass specific key/value with prepare segue between multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue

I try to pass data through prepare(for segue) method but I can't get passed data in the ReceiverViewController. I wonder I would better pass the whole instance, don't know if it is possible.
I am a newbie on Swift and this is my first try, any advice would be welcome.

The class I want to use is the following - UserClass.swift :

```
class User {
    var firstname: String
    var lastname: String
    var role: Int

    init(firstname: String, lastname: String, role: Int) {
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.role = role
    }

}
```

My prepare method on FirstViewController.swift

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "loadBoard" {
        if let dVC = segue.destination as? ReceiverViewController {
            dVC.code?.firstname = anotherValue

            //Following show me nil
            print("Sent data \(dVC.code?.firstname)")
        }
    }
 }
```

Here is what I tried to get the data - ReceiverViewController.swift :

```
var code: User?

if let test = self.code?.firstname {
    self.categoryLabel.text = code?.firstname
    print(code)
} else {
    print("Something wrong")
}
```

Comment: Are you initialising the `code` property somewhere in your code?

Comment: Pass the whole instance. It should work.

Comment: Passing data between controllers isn't difficult but it can be a little confusing. [This example](https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-potato) shows how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

prepareForSegue is called before the destination viewController's viewDidLoad.  If you're relying on the code property being set to a User during ReceiverViewController's viewDidLoad, then your approach won't work.

So you'll need to either set the code property of ReceiverViewController during prepareForSegue or set another property of ReceiverViewController with the firstname then get firstname assigned to code during ReceiverViewController's viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 0):

In `prepareForSegue` you are attempting to set a property on `code: User?` which is an uninitialized object. What you can do instead is pass an initialized `User` object in your call to `performSegue` and then do the following:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "loadBoard" {
        if let dVC = segue.destination as? ReceiverViewController,
            let user = sender as? User {
                dVC.code = user

        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to send and receive data from one controller to another.

prepareForSegue is called before the destination controller is loaded. 
Because of this, elements on the destination controller cannot be set inside the sending controller.
The approach here is to set some other variable with the data to send.
In the destination view controller, process the data in viewWillAppear.

The sending controller:

```
//  https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-potato
//  ViewController.swift
//  data-share
//
//  Created by ryan teixeira on 3/21/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Ryan Teixeira. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var helloTextField: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {
            print("detail segue")
            let destinationController = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
            destinationController.helloText = helloTextField.text
        }
    }
}
```

The receiving view controller:

```
//  https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-potato
//  DetailViewController.swift
//  data-share
//
//  Created by ryan teixeira on 3/21/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 Ryan Teixeira. All rights reserved.
//
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var helloText: String?
    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: UILabel!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        helloLabel.text = helloText
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation
    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```